# Encrypted connection throwing error "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: ssl, hana

Any ideas wellcome:

HANA 2.0.44 with encryped connection from windows clients using ODBC driver 2.5.105 (with trust to the server): We observer sporadic errors using a DSN-based connection:

```
[SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Communication link failure;-10709 Connection failed (RTE:[1000013] The system cannot find the file specified. (server:port))
```

In some situations the errors are correlated to privileges of the user. In some situations the error an be removed by testing the connection within ODBC-Manager. Sometime it looks like there is a correlation to the reuse of the same connection - sometimes this works withour problems. The error can be reproduced within DSN-less (driver-based) connections.

Any ideas how to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is not clear about whether the issue occurs on the client- or the server-side of the communication the investigation should look at both ends.

For the server-side the *nameserver* and *indexserver* trace files are the ones to check.

For the client-side I think the best option here is to use the [ODBC trace option](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.5/en-US/35368f78f6884b019caee12c125b255a.html) of the HANA ODBC driver.

The tool to use here is called `hdbodbc_cons` (located in the folder of the HANA client) and the linked documentation explains the different options in detail.

Comment: hdbodbc_cons would only trace something, when the error does _not_ occur. As soon the connection would throw the error there is nothiing to be traced at the client side (not even at package level). The error must occur before the ODBC-driver enters the game.

Comment: That’s not correct. The error message clearly comes from the ODBC driver. The tracing facility covers the whole API of the driver; so all methods of it can be traced (use the `API` trace topic).

Comment: It seems that the path (i.e. in parameter "sslkeystore") must not use windows style back slash. With forward slash I did not see the error again. Maybe the ODBC-driver does not accept a regular windows style path.